# How to prevent browser back button after successful login in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am having a problem applying custom middleware for not accessing the login route after successful login. Whenever I logged in a user if the user press the browser back button he was able to see the login page again. To prevent this I have created a middleware and disabled the cache inside its handle method but it was not working because I have multiple roles.
Here is my middleware code:-
My middleware name is **RevalidateBackHistory** and I have register it in the kernal.php file with **revalidate** name like this:-

```
'revalidate' => \App\Http\Middleware\RevalidateBackHistory::class,
```

in the **protected $routeMiddleware** group.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
        ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
        ->header('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
}
```

Here is my web.php file:-

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest', 'revalidate'], 'prefix' => '/'], function(){
....my guest route here
}

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'revalidate']], function() {
....my auth routes here
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin', 'revalidate'], 'namespace' => 'Backend'], function () {
    ...my admin role routes here
    }

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:user', 'revalidate'], 'namespace' => 'Backend'], function () {
    ...my user role routes here
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine for the single role but not with multiple roles because my login function is common for both the users (admin and user).
What can I add in to my code to prevent the browser back button not to worked after login and vice versa for after logout.

Please help me out!

Comment: back button is component  of the browser you can disable it using JavaScript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would do the following.

I would create a redirect on the login page if I was authorized or only show login page when not authorized. Basically the opposit of when you want to go to an unauthorized page.

again ignore the groups and only if a user is authenticated

in laraval if you have auth()->user() the user has already been validated so no need to login again. and redirect to your backend